# jqgrid minimize functionality in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to add minimize option to jqgrid add / edit form. I didn't find any property / way in the documentation.

```
).navGrid('#mypager',{ 
        cloneToTop:true,
        edit:false,
        add:true,
        del:false
    },
    {//edit code here},
    {//add code here}
);
```

Is there any way we can add minimize functionality to add / edit form of jqgrid?

Comment: did you try `hiddengrid:true`?

Comment: @Sina `hiddengrid` property is used to expand, collapse `grid`, I am trying to minimize the `form`

Comment: Ah now I see what you mean, I doubt if there's anything by default for that. Did you try getting this done by jQuery? Or you're looking for a better solution?

Comment: @Sina I can get it done by using jquery dialog, But then I will have to write custom code i.e. custom button, load the data in to form, and then client side validations and all.. So before doing that I am looking for a way (if there is any) by which it can be achived using jqgrid form.

Comment: @Bhushan: "minimize" functionality is not standard, thus the exact semantic is not full clear. What should be displayed after minimizing? Can one minimize multiple dialogs? Should be the minimized icons (titles) movable (via drag and drop). I can show how add the button to the title of dialogs and to hide/show overlay and add of cause custom `click` event handler. All other logic (working with minimized visual element on the windows) should be youth. Would be enough such information for you?

Comment: @Oleg, sorry for late reply, Yes Its enough..